# Pagestyle plain. No page number on last page of chapter

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am using plain pagestyle. Last page of every chapter doesn't have page number.
This is my master page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,11pt,wide,floatssmall]{mwrep}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[sort, compress]{cite}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\raggedbottom
\input {title}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\input {chap_a}
\input {chap_b}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Files: chap_a, chap_b contains text. Chapter chap_a and chap_b are two A4 pages long. Second page of chap_a doesn't have page number. chap_a.tex and chap_b.tex files are identical:

```
\chapter {WSS}
\label{chap:wss}
\section{WSS}
aa bb ...
aa bb

\subsection{BBAA}
bb aa ...
bb aa

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "main"
%%% End:
```

How can I put page number on these pages?

---

Hint:
When I change pagestyle: pagestyle{headings} instead of pagestyle{plain} I have page numbers on every page in header except first page in every chapter, which doesn't have page number in footer (I read that it should have).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's inside of `chap_a.tex` etc? `\pagenumbering{arabic}` sets the page number to `1` usually, it's not necessary to use `\setcounter{page}{1}` explicitly

Comment: The class redefines `\cleardoublepage` so that if it needs to make an empty page to get the next chapter open on the right it uses the `blank` page style rather than the default one. that seems to be a major aim of the class but `\makeatletter\let\ps@blank\ps@plain\makeatother` probably changes it.

Comment: `hyperref` should be the **last** package to be loaded, in most cases

Comment: @David Carlisle - I put this line before \begin{document} and it doesn't work. Still no page number.

Comment: Add this to the preamble: `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina This works!

Comment: Usually people want to achieve exactly that behaviour ;-) Where did you get the class? If you are required to use this, you might be required to have those pages completely blank.

Comment: This class is a part of unofficial document. I realized that my document must have page number on every page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\ps@normal\hf@plain
  \let\ps@opening\hf@plain
  \let\ps@closing\hf@plain
  \let\ps@blank\hf@empty
  \ps@normal}
\makeatother
```

just before

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

and the problem is solved.