# Custom page numbers fail on last page of included chapters

Tags: page-numbering, include

**TL;DR when I include an appendix into my master report, the custom page numbering fails on the last page of each appendix.  How can I fix it?**

I am creating a long report with appendices.  I want roman page numbering for my preamble, arabic for the main body, and [custom page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59574/96128) in the appendices, in the form `A1, A2,...`.  It is all working fine, except that the last page of each appendix is reverting to standard arabic numerals, e.g. `3` rather than `A3`.  The problem appears to be linked to the fact that I am including these appendices from separate files.

In the following MWE, the two appendices in the main file are numbered correctly, but the included file is not:

**Main file**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{standalone}         % Allow included files to also be compiled standalone
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}             % For testing

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \pagestyle{plain}

    \tableofcontents

    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \lipsum

    \appendix
    \pretocmd{\chapter}{%
      \clearpage
      \pagenumbering{arabic}%
      \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter\arabic{page}}%
    }{}{}

    \chapter{First appendix}
    \lipsum

    \include{include}

    \chapter{Third appendix}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

**include.tex**

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Included appendix}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

I have tried the solution to [Pagestyle plain. No page number on last page of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225031/96128).  It just gave me undefined control sequence errors.

How can I ensure that the page number on the last page of the included file gets the same formatting as the other appendix pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

standalone adds additional grouping and so your redefinition of \thepage gets lost. Move it directly behind \appendix and reset the page number with setcounter instead of pagenumbering:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{standalone}         % Allow included files to also be compiled standalone
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}             % For testing

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \pagestyle{plain}

    \tableofcontents

    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \lipsum

    \appendix
    \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter\arabic{page}}%
    \pretocmd{\chapter}{%
      \clearpage
      \setcounter{page}{1}%
    }{}{}

    \chapter{First appendix}
    \lipsum

    \include{include}

    \chapter{Third appendix}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```